# Rust cannot infer Fn type where Option<Fn> is None

Tags: generics, rust, type-inference

So I have [this situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0a31eb70a1e5a17d3ecaf53e3724063d), where Rust cannot infer the generic type arguments for a function, that takes and optional Fn as a parameter.
When passing `None` into it, it seems like the generic type arguments are obsolete, but Rust needs to know their values to compile and I don't know what to tell him. I tried `foo::<(), ()>(calculation_result, None)`, but that doesn't work.

Does anyone know how I can call this `foo` function when passing `None` instead of a closure into it? Is there a dummy type I can specify or something?

Comment: Since you return `MyResult<R>` from `foo()`, you will also need to decide, what `R` should be in that case. This all smells like a fundamental misunderstanding of Rust's type system and like an x/y problem to me.

Comment: Yes I know, but for `R` I believe `()` will do, since there is no bound on `R`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is to call a function with an unspecified parameter.

```
fn foo<F, R>(arg: bool, f: Option<F>) -> MyResult<R>
    where F: Fn() -> R
{...}

foo(true, None); // <- R cannot be inferred
```

You have to manually specify the type. Keep in mind that Option gets optimised to the size of Box (not sizeof Box + 1) and does not allocate in the None case.

```
let empty: Option<Box<dyn Fn() -> ()>> = None;
foo(true, empty); // <- R is (), Option<Box<>>::None does not allocate
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue that has bitten many libraries in the ecosystem, such as [Gtk](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk3-rs/stable/latest/docs/gtk/struct.Application.html#associatedconstant.NONE):

Currently the best workaround I know is to declare a constant with the relevant `None` values of a dummy type, as the `Gtk` crate I linked above.

In your particular case, the easier type to use as `F` is a basic `fn()` and the syntax to annotate `None` is a turbo-fish such as: `Option::<fn()>::None`.

Comment: Note that there's a slightly shorter turbofish alternative of `None::<fn()>`.

Comment: @user4815162342: Oh, nice! I seem to remember trying that some time ago and it didn't work. Is that a recent syntax or is my memory faulty?

Comment: It [worked in 1.0.0](https://godbolt.org/z/jhdhToeeo), so I guess it's not new! Maybe you omitted the `::` and tried `None<fn()>`? That sometimes (still) happens to me.